# insert multiple line in array and compare array in bash

Tags: python, arrays, bash, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to transform an array ( file c )  using bash 4.1. I also tried with python/numpy but I am a newbie and I do not understand it very well yet. Here is my problem:

I have the following array:

```
1 E
2 A
3 Z
5 R
6 A
8 A
```

and I want to add a line when there is an increment superior to 1 in my array as:

```
1 E
2 A 
3 Z
4 change 
5 R
6 A
7 change
8 A
```

I tried to do that with this code:

```
        i=1
        while read s t; do
             if [[ $i = $s ]];
             then echo "$s $t" >> e
             else echo "$i change" >> e ; s=$s[$(($i-1))]
             fi

        i=$(($i+1))
        done < c
```

But I have this result:

```
1 E
2 A 
3 Z
4 change 
5 change
6 change
7 change
8 change
```

Coud you please help me to resolve this problem?
In advance, 
Thank you! 
Basarab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is rarely the best approach to process lines in a file one by one in native bash. Here's one way you could do it using the standard tool awk, which is designed to process data of this form:

```
awk '{while($1!=++last)print last+1,"change"}{last=$1;print}' file.txt
```

Awk processes each line in the file, one by one. Until the value of the first field is the same as `last+1`, insert a row with "change". Always print the current record that is being processed and save the current value of the first field to the variable `last`, so it can be used when processing the next line.

A common shorthand in awk can be used to remove the need for the second `print`:

```
awk '{while($1!=++last)print last+1,"change"}{last=$1}1' file.txt
```

The format of an awk script is `rule { action }`. The default action is `{print}` and `1` is the shortest rule that always evaluates to true, so every line is printed.

Comment: No problem, I have updated the code to work with gaps in the input greater than 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in bash, you weren't very far from it:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
while read s t;
do
    while [[ $s != $i ]]
    do
        echo "$i change"
        i=$((i+1))
    done
    echo "$s $t"
    i=$((i+1))
done < c
```

Now you can do: `./bash_script > output` to write this to a file.